# Is there a way to add an 'Import' to a project in a VS extension?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I want to add a new `<Import>` to a project when I detect that a particular type of file has been added to the project. (the `<Import>` adds a task to the build process that takes the file and performs work during a build).

(Detection of a file having been added to the project is done using `IVsSolutionEvents.HandleItemAdded`).

I currently have code that uses `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project` to add an Import element to the project. However this is an edit to a project file on disk. If I use this code to add an Import after detecting the addition of a new item to the project **I create a conflict between a change on disk (the new Import) and an in-memory change (the addition of the new file)**. The user is then presented with a dialog where they must choose which change to throw away.

My question is this:

Is there a way to add a new `<Import>` to a project via the visual studio extensibility API in such a way that the modification to the project would be "in-memory", avoiding a conflict between the addition of the new project item, and the addition of the Import?

Comment: Is this for an existing project type (e.g. C# projects), or a custom project type you have defined in the extension (e.g. using MPFProj or the Common Project System)?

Comment: It is for existing project types.

Answer (score 1):

For existing project types, I've found the easiest way is leveraging NuGet. You can define a NuGet package which contains the **.targets** file in a special **build/** folder, and NuGet will [automatically add the `<Import>`](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Import_MSBuild_targets_and_props_files_into_project_(Requires_NuGet_2.5_or_above)) when it is added to a project within Visual Studio. It will also update the references if you upgrade the package in the future. A full example is the packaging of the [Antlr4BuildTasks](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/tree/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks) package, which currently uses the following **.nuspec** file to create the package. The key here is the section following the `<!-- Build Configuration -->` comment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="2.7">
    <id>Antlr4</id>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
    <authors>Sam Harwell, Terence Parr</authors>
    <owners>Sam Harwell</owners>
    <description>The C# target of the ANTLR 4 parser generator for Visual Studio 2010+ projects. This package supports projects targeting .NET 2.0 or newer, and built using Visual Studio 2010 or newer.</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs</projectUrl>
    <licenseUrl>https://raw.github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/master/LICENSE.txt</licenseUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://raw.github.com/antlr/website-antlr4/master/images/icons/antlr.png</iconUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright © Sam Harwell 2014</copyright>
    <releaseNotes>https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/releases/v$version$</releaseNotes>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>true</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>
    <tags>antlr antlr4 parsing</tags>
    <title>ANTLR 4</title>
    <summary>The C# target of the ANTLR 4 parser generator for Visual Studio 2010+ projects.</summary>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Antlr4.Runtime" version="$version$" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <!-- Tools -->

    <file src="..\tool\target\antlr4-csharp-$CSharpToolVersion$-complete.jar" target="tools"/>

    <!-- Build Configuration -->

    <file src="..\runtime\CSharp\Antlr4BuildTasks\bin\net40\$Configuration$\Antlr4.net40.props" target="build\Antlr4.props"/>
    <file src="..\runtime\CSharp\Antlr4BuildTasks\bin\net40\$Configuration$\Antlr4.net40.targets" target="build\Antlr4.targets"/>
    <file src="..\runtime\CSharp\Antlr4BuildTasks\bin\net40\$Configuration$\Antlr4BuildTasks.net40.dll" target="build"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Thanks - it's interesting that NuGet can add imports like this. I wonder how they're doing it. I suppose the code is open source so I could take a look.

Comment: I recommend using NuGet itself, rather than reimplementing it. This gives you the option of easily working with machines where your extension is not installed. You can always embed the **.nupkg** file within your **.vsix** file, and use the NuGet API to install the package from there without requiring it to be published online.

Comment: The extension contains menu items/editors so it doesn't make much sense for it not to be installed and to be able to add the import to peoples' projects. However I'll take a look at using NuGet - not sure whether that means people then need to use NuGet and they'll see an uninstallable 'package' for the modified project...